# Storing REST requests with service workers to sync them

Tags: javascript, offline, service-worker

I'm thinking about taking my application to offline using service workers. I'm already achieving satisfying results with caching resources, but I also have to check onfetch whether I'm connected to the internet, if not - store the request, and push it onsync. 
I understand, that future onsync will help with that, but I need - even temporary - solution for that.
I've tried just to store the requests in an array within worker, but it's not persistent - doesn't work after computer restart (while SW works and serves offline content). 
What's the good direction - storing it in cache like files somehow? Or using IndexedDB / SimpleDB ([Accessing indexedDB in ServiceWorker. Race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206836/accessing-indexeddb-in-serviceworker-race-condition/29220096#29220096))?

Comment: It's not very clear what is your issue. If your question is whether IndexedDB can be used for offline storage, then yes, it can. If you don't know how to do your storage operations so that they support both online and offline modes, then you can see what they suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342836/syncing-indexeddb-with-sql-server

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a way to store POST requests within Service Worker when I'm offline in order to sync them when I'll go on-line. Storing them in IndexedDB could be an answer, but IndexedDB isn't supported by [Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-service-worker/blob/master/README.md), and it's the only way to use Service Workers now on iOS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's an example at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/service-worker/offline-analytics of using a service worker to detect failures for certain types of requests (in this case, Google Analytics pings via HTTP `GET`), and queue up the failures using `IndexedDB`. The queue is examined each time the service worker starts up and if the request can be successfully "replayed" (because the network is now available), it's removed from the queue. While there are no guarantees about when a service worker will start up (background sync events will help with that in the future), you can safely assume that if the someone is actively using your web app, the service worker will revive itself.

This can be generalized to other types of requests, like HTTP `POST`s, but there are a few things to think about:

- Make sure your users are aware that their HTTP `POST` is being queued and will be replayed. Since HTTP `POST`s normally modify server-side state, you don't want to surprise users when something changes as a result of a replayed request that's X hours old.
- Depending on what service you're calling, HTTP `POST`s might require a valid `Authorization` header. If you're using OAuth 2 for authorization, it may use access tokens which have a limited lifespan. A previously valid Authorization token might be expired by the time you replay the request.
- `IndexedDB` is a good choice for queueing your requests, since it offers flexibility in storing arbitrary data, and it should be possible to, e.g., store the HTTP `POST`'s body without much work. If you can't use `IndexedDB` (you say it's not supported using [Cordova](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-service-worker/blob/master/README.md)), then the only other option I could think of would be to try to make use of the [Cache Storage API](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#cache-objects) to create a new "queue" cache, with failed `Request`s as the keys and empty `Response` objects as the values. At service worker startup, you could use the [`keys()`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#cache-keys) method on your "queue" cache to get a list of all the `Requests`, and for each `queuedRequest`, call `fetch(queuedRequest)` to replay it. I have not tried this approach before, but I think it should work.

Comment: Can anybody provide an example of how to store the HTTP POST's body into IndexedDB and later retrieve it?

Comment: thank you jeff, can you please provide a code snippet for storing the post request with header to IndexedDb and triggering the call once application online