# Workbox - add header to cached response

Tags: javascript, caching, workbox

i'm using workbox-sw to cache some API requests and I'm wondering if it is possible to add custom header to responses that were returned from the cache.

my sw.js looks like this:

```
importScripts('workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.1.js');

const workboxSW = new WorkboxSW();

workboxSW.precache([]);
workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://api\.url/'),
  workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'api-cache',
    cacheExpiration: {
      maxEntries: 10,
      maxAgeSeconds: 3600 * 24
    },
    cacheableResponse: {statuses: [200]}
  })
);
```

Any idea how to add a header to response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little buried in the docs, but you can use a function that implements the [`handlerCallback` interface](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#handling_a_route_with_a_custom_callback) to perform custom actions when a `Route` matches, like so:

```
const cacheFirstStrategy = workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
  cacheName: 'api-cache',
  cacheExpiration: {
    maxEntries: 10,
    maxAgeSeconds: 3600 * 24
  },
  cacheableResponse: {statuses: [200]}
});

workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://api\.url/'),
  async ({event, url}) => {
    const cachedResponse = await cacheFirstStrategy.handle({event, url});
    if (cachedResponse) {
      cachedResponse.headers.set('x-custom-header', 'my-value');
    }
    return cachedResponse;
  }
);
```

Comment: chrome complains - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'set' on 'Headers': Headers are immutable

Comment: @denov take look at another Jeff's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30063346/2234964 that's possible way to avoid this error.